# How to get back stationary data from non stationary data after performing diff operations in var (time series)?

Tags: python, time-series, pandas

I have applied var model on multiple features ,but var model accepts the stationary data so i have converted non-stationary data to stationary data by doing diff() ,given the data to var model.
what my question is ,is their option get back  data normal data from stationary to non-stationary  in time series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to add the resulting time series. The cumulative sums are comparable to your original input.

Comment: Thanks for the comments,i am doing difference na , suppose 30 and 20 are my points difference 10 , we have many combinations to get 10 differences how can i remembered original one in this , thats is why my mail probelm ,

Comment: just give a simple example so that i can understand easily from that get to apply to my code.

Comment: Let's say the last data point you have is 30. You predict a differenced series 5, -7, -1. You are predicting their cumulative sum then: 35, 28, 27

Comment: ok i got it pandas having cumsum() function by using that we can achieve that one ,thanks